# Change page number when observing an event

Tags: r, shiny, pagination

I'm using `shinyThings::paginationUI` & `shinyThings::pager` to create a pagination as follows:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyThings)

ui <- fluidPage(
  shiny::selectInput(inputId = "input_id",label = "Random Input", choices = c("A", "B", "C"), selected = "A"),
  shinyThings::paginationUI("page_id", width = 12, offset = 4, class = "text-center")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  shinyThings::pager("page_id", n_items = 16, page_break = 4)
  
}

# start the app
shiny::shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Assume the user selects "A" from the `selectInput` and selects page number 2 from the `paginationUI`. How can I reset the `paginationUI` to page number 1 automatically when the user selects "B" from the `selectInput`? If this is not possible with `shinyThings`, is there a different package I can use to create this?

I have tried to add and `observe event` like this but with no luck.

```
 library(shiny)
library(shinyThings)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput(inputId = "input_id",label = "Random Input", choices = c("A", "B", "C"), selected = "A"),
  shinyThings::paginationUI("page_id", width = 12, offset = 4, class = "text-center"),
  verbatimTextOutput("page_indices")
  
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  page_indices <- shinyThings::pager("page_id", n_items = 16, page_break = 4)
 
   output$page_indices <- renderPrint({
    page_indices()
  })
  
  reactive_input <- reactive({
    input$input_id
  })

  observeEvent(reactive_input(), {
    #do something to change page_indices()
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.3.0 (2023-04-21)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices datasets  utils     methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] shinyThings_0.4.0 shiny_1.7.4      

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] digest_0.6.31    later_1.3.0      R6_2.5.1         httpuv_1.6.9     fastmap_1.1.1    magrittr_2.0.3   cachem_1.0.7     bspm_0.5.1      
 [9] memoise_2.0.1    htmltools_0.5.5  lifecycle_1.0.3  promises_1.2.0.1 cli_3.6.1        xtable_1.8-4     vctrs_0.6.1      sass_0.4.5      
[17] rsconnect_0.8.29 renv_0.16.0      jquerylib_0.1.4  compiler_4.3.0   purrr_1.0.1      rstudioapi_0.14  tools_4.3.0      ellipsis_0.3.2  
[25] mime_0.12        bslib_0.4.2      Rcpp_1.0.10      rlang_1.1.0      jsonlite_1.8.4   shinyjs_2.1.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one solution which uses a little bit of custom `JS`.

[image]

The basic idea here is to put an `onChange` event on your `selectInput` which manipulates the `class` attributes of the pagination. In this example, the reset is invoked each time the `selectInput` receives a change, but you can of course extend this.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyThings)

js <- HTML(
"
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#input_id').selectize({
        onChange: function(value) {
          
            $('[id^=page_id-page_0]').each(function() {
                $(this)[0].parentElement.setAttribute('class', 'page-item');
            });

            $('#page_id-page_001')[0].parentElement.setAttribute('class', 'page-item active');
        }
    });
});
"
)

ui <- fluidPage(
    tags$head(tags$script(js)),
    shiny::selectInput(inputId = "input_id",label = "Random Input", choices = c("A", "B", "C"), selected = "A"),
    shinyThings::paginationUI("page_id", width = 12, offset = 4, class = "text-center")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    shinyThings::pager("page_id", n_items = 16, page_break = 4)
}

# start the app
shiny::shinyApp(ui, server)
```